# Given a set of numeric values, calculate the combination that gives the result

Tags: sql, math, combinations, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server query that shows me all the Agent jobs that run on a weekly basis. I want to be able work out which days they run on.

I have the following query

```
SELECT  j.name,
        CASE
            WHEN s.freq_type = 4 OR (s.freq_type = 8 AND freq_interval = 2) -- a job with a daily recurrance or weekly on this day
            THEN 1
        END AS Monday,
        CASE
            WHEN s.freq_type = 4 OR (s.freq_type = 8 AND freq_interval = 3) 
            THEN 1
        END AS Tuesday,
        CASE
            WHEN s.freq_type = 4 OR (s.freq_type = 8 AND freq_interval = 4) 
            THEN 1
        END AS Wednesday,
        CASE
            WHEN s.freq_type = 4 OR (s.freq_type = 8 AND freq_interval = 5) 
            THEN 1
        END AS Thursday,
        CASE
            WHEN s.freq_type = 4 OR (s.freq_type = 8 AND freq_interval = 6) 
            THEN 1
        END AS Friday,
        CASE
            WHEN s.freq_type = 4 OR (s.freq_type = 8 AND freq_interval = 7) 
            THEN 1
        END AS Saturday,
        CASE
            WHEN s.freq_type = 4 OR (s.freq_type = 8 AND freq_interval = 1) 
            THEN 1
        END AS Sunday,
        s.freq_interval
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules js
        JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules s
            ON js.schedule_id = s.schedule_id
        JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
            ON js.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE   j.enabled = 1 AND
        s.enabled = 1 AND
        s.freq_type = 8
```

The `s.freq_interval` column is the sum of a combination of values as follows

```
1 = Sunday
2 = Monday
4 = Tuesday
8 = Wednesday
16 = Thursday
32 = Friday
64 = Saturday
```

Therefore if a job is scheduled to run on a Tuesday and a Thursday, `s.freq_interva`l will be 4+16=**20**
If a job is scheduled to run a Friday, Saturday and Sunday, s.freq_interval will be 32+64+1=**97**

How do I take the value in s.freq_interval and work out the combination of values which sums to that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `&` bitwise operator to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(1 ,'Sunday'),
            (2 ,'Monday'),
            (4 ,'Tuesday'),
            (8 ,'Wednesday'),
            (16,'Thursday'),
            (32,'Friday'),
            (64,'Saturday'))V(FrequencyInt, FrequnecyDay)
     JOIN (VALUES(20),(97),(13),(8)) J(Freq) ON V.Frequencyint & J.Freq != 0;
```

Comment: Thanks - adapted this for my solution